# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

```
/* Определяем текущую дату */
$cdate = date("Y-m-d");

/* Составляем запрос для вставки информации в таблицу
name...date - название конкретных полей в базе;
в $_POST["test_name"]... $_POST["test_mess"] - в этих переменных содержатся данные, полученные из формы */
$query = 
"INSERT INTO $table SET 
kod='".$_POST["kod_f"]."', 
name='".$_POST["name_f"]."',
tovar='".$_POST["tovar_f"]."', 
state='".$_POST["state_f"]."', 
price='".$_POST["price_f"]."';

/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

/* Закрываем соединение */
mysql_close();

/* Ругается: на эту строку: on line 39
echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\"">
<font color=\"green\">Данные успешно сохранены!</font>
 */
<a href=\"index.html\">Вернуться назад</a></div>");

?>


echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\"">
```

Код ошибки:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in W:\domains\s.ru\save.php on line 39
```

Comment: @Сергій Костючок, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

```
 echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\">
<font color=\"green\">Данные успешно сохранены!</font>
 */
<a href=\"index.html\">Вернуться назад</a></div>");
```

У Вас была лишняя двойная кавычка в этом куске кода. А вообще тег font устарел.

А в этом куске кода двойной кавычки не хватает в конце:

```
 $query = 
"INSERT INTO $table SET 
kod='".$_POST["kod_f"]."', 
name='".$_POST["name_f"]."',
tovar='".$_POST["tovar_f"]."', 
state='".$_POST["state_f"]."', 
price='".$_POST["price_f"]."'";
```